# How to trigger a jQuery function to load again after another jQuery is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not that great with jQuery but basically, I have a jQuery that displays when scrolling down, new content.

But that new content has div that are under effect of another jQuery function that is called by `ready`.

So not it only the content that is loaded first when the page loads is working but when the new content is showing is not working on it to.

So I'm thinking maybe I can link the two jQuerys like a trigger when the second jQuery loads to execute the first one, is it possible? How?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
        $('.wrapper-hover').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).animate({opacity:'1'});
            },
            function () {
                $(this).animate({opacity:'0'});
            }
        );  
    };
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have already?  It will make fixing your issue much easier.

Comment: @NickLarsen sure, i have the infinite scroll jquery that is targeted for an `id` on a `div`, and i have the jquery from the update, i need the jquery from above to execute after the loading `each time` of the infinite scroll

Comment: Are you trying to attach the hover event to the class `.wrapper-hover` every time its rendered? If you are, you might think about looking into event delegation.

Comment: @user1506980 i'm trying to attach infinite scroll event to hover, after scoll event takes place, to re-execute the hover. how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with `callback` of the infinite scroll jquery. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jquery [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger an event and then have something listen for that event

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    //your event handler
    $('body').on('event', function() {
        $('.wrapper-hover').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).animate({opacity:'1'});
            },
            function () {
                $(this).animate({opacity:'0'});
            }
        );  
    });
};

//when your inifinite scroll finishes trigger the event
$('body').trigger('event');
```

If all you're doing is attaching a hover event to that class you might also want to think about [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), still not sure what your intention is based on your question.

Comment: don't quite know how to use it in my situation :(

Comment: Just edited it. Also don't downvote me because you didn't explain your question originally.

Comment: Ah it just looked that way. Can you post more code or a link to the infinite scroll plugin you used?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want a hover event on a div which works well when the page is loaded but it doesn't work when a new div renders. If this is so then try the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
            $('.wrapper-hover').on("mouseenter", function() {
                $(this).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000,
                        function() {
                            $(this).animate({opacity: '1'});
                        });
            });
        });
```